# UITextView link tap recognition is delayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

In an iOS 7 app, I have a `UITextView` with a link in it, but tapping the link doesn't fire. It only responds to an awkward "tap and hold". I want it to respond as soon as a user taps on it, like how a `UIWebView` link tap works. Here is my setup:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."];
    [text addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"myurl://tapped" range:NSMakeRange(6, 16)];

    self.textView.attributedText = text;
    self.textView.editable = NO;
    self.textView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
    if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"myurl"])
    {
        // Handle tap

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

The Apple Documentation for the `shouldInteractWithURL` method states: "The text view calls this method if the user taps or long-presses the URL link". The long-press is working, but the tap doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how to get this to respond immediately?

Comment: Link tap recognition is delayed still happening in iOS9 :((((((

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is the `UITextView` selectable?. Try with:

```
self.textView.selectable = YES;
```

Edit:

I'm starting to think that maybe a long-press is the only way to fire it contrary to what apple says. Check this [link](https://github.com/choefele/CCHLinkTextView), maybe it will help.

Comment: It is selectable. The problem isn't that the link doesn't work. It's that the user has to do a delayed touch on it.

Comment: Could be a bug now fixed in iOS 7.1?

[link](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1691855). Try disabling scrolling as workaround.

Comment: I am using 7.1 - just updated yesterday and verified this was how it works in both 7.0 and 7.1.

Comment: Found possible workarounds:

`[self.textView setText:nil]` before setting the URL. 
`self.textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;` 
`[self.textView.scrollEnabled:NO];`

Comment: Thanks - I tried these settings as well, but there was no change to the behavior.

Comment: I'm starting to think that maybe a long-press is the only way to fire it contrary to what apple says. Check this [link](https://github.com/choefele/CCHLinkTextView), maybe it will help.

Comment: nnarayann, it will need a few modifications, but I this should give me what I want. If you add this suggestion into an answer, I will mark yours as correct.

Comment: I am facing the same problem where the user has to long-press a link detected by `dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink`.  Seems like CCHLinkTextView doesn't support quick tapping URL links unfortunately.

Answer (score 41):

If you still want to go with a native `UITextView`, you can add a tap recognizer to your textview and get the string attributes at the tap location. When you find a link, you can open it immediately.

I wrote a Gist that solves this for iOS 7/8. It's a lightweight extension of `UITextView` that also forwards `-[UITextViewDelegate textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:]` and exposes the internal tap gesture recognizer.

https://gist.github.com/benjaminbojko/c92ac19fe4db3302bd28

<strike>Here's a quick example:</strike>The example below only works on iOS 8. See the gist above for iOS 7 + 8 support.

Add your tap recognizer:

```
// ...

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedTextView:)];
[myTextView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
myTextView.selectable = YES; // otherwise the gesture won't recognize

// ...
```

And add your callback:

```
- (void)tappedTextView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    if (tapGesture.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        return;
    }

    UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)tapGesture.view;
    CGPoint tapLocation = [tapGesture locationInView:textView];
    UITextPosition *textPosition = [textView closestPositionToPoint:tapLocation];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [textView textStylingAtPosition:textPosition inDirection:UITextStorageDirectionForward];

    NSURL *url = attributes[NSLinkAttributeName];

    if (url) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}
```

And swift version:

Tap recognizer:

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tappedTextView:"))
myTextView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
myTextView.selectable = true
```

Callback:

```
func tappedTextView(tapGesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        let textView = tapGesture.view as! UITextView
        let tapLocation = tapGesture.locationInView(textView)
        let textPosition = textView.closestPositionToPoint(tapLocation)
        let attr: NSDictionary = textView.textStylingAtPosition(textPosition, inDirection: UITextStorageDirection.Forward)

        if let url: NSURL = attr[NSLinkAttributeName] as? NSURL {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }

        }
```

Comment: I just tried this on iOS 7, and it looks like the textView can't find the link attribute at all. Have you had any luck with this on iOS 7?

Comment: @BobVork Right, I remember having some cross-version issues. Ultimately, it became a little tricky to get the attributes with `textStylingAtPosition:inDirection:` on iOS 7. I assume that it had to do with the textPosition having a length of 0, and therefore the attributed string had no characters to actually host any link information. Just a thought.

Ultimately I wrote this Gist that works for me across iOS 7 and 8: https://gist.github.com/benjaminbojko/c92ac19fe4db3302bd28

Comment: Note that instead of "NSURL", it could be an "NSString" depending on how you setup the URL.

Comment: Swift 4: ```@objc func tappedTextView(tapGesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let textView = tapGesture.view as! UITextView
        let tapLocation = tapGesture.location(in: textView)
        let textPosition = textView.closestPosition(to: tapLocation)
        let attr = textView.textStyling(at: textPosition!, in: .forward)!
        if let url: URL = attr[NSAttributedStringKey.link.rawValue] as? URL {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }```

Answer (score 7):

As nnarayann mentioned, [CCHLinkTextView](https://github.com/choefele/CCHLinkTextView) avoids the problem of delayed tap recognition. This library implements its own gesture recognizer and is now available in version 1.0.

Comment: Nice library! It took only 2 minutes to include the pod and adjust existing code in my swift project. Works perfectly. Also, the attribute takes a value of any type instead of a NSURL. It is just perfect if you need to pass something else like an index. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4** solution

---

- Handles links using tap gesture recognizer
- Whether `isSelectable` is `true` or `false`, it works

---

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLinkTap(_:)))
textView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

@objc func handleLinkTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: textView)
    guard
        let textPosition = textView.closestPosition(to: tapLocation),
        let url = textView.textStyling(at: textPosition, in: .forward)?[NSAttributedStringKey.link.rawValue],
        let urlString = (url as? String) ?? (url as? URL)?.absoluteString,
        urlString == "myurl"
    else { return }

    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    // Do whatever you want with this URL, such as
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: Use this: 

`let urlString = textView.textStyling(at: textPosition, in: .forward)?[NSAttributedStringKey.link.rawValue] as? URL, urlString == "myurl"
    else { return }`

Instead of:

`let urlString = textView.textStyling(at: textPosition, in: .forward)?[NSAttributedStringKey.link.rawValue] as? String, urlString == "myurl"
    else { return }`

Comment: Are you sure? because (as I remember) I tried to cast the result as URL, I guess it failed, I will recheck to make sure (soon as possible) if it works

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Check from your side as well

Comment: I have figure out, It depends on link attribute. I have given URL. It can also take String

Comment: Rechecked @RasheshBosamiya, value for `textStyling[NSAttributedStringKey.link.rawValue]` is NSString which fails on casting to URL, you can create `URL.init(string: urlString)` if necessary

Comment: Yes, Have provided  URL as link attribute. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it saved me today *It depends on link attribute.* answer updated to support both cases

Comment: Great! Nice to hear you after little long time. Thanks for be in touch.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's not working on the iOS Simulator or only work if you tap & hold.

You should test it on a real device.

And don't forget to set it `selectable`.

Comment: Not sure why this answer is up-voted, because I see the same behaviour for this problem on the simulator and a real device.

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't any pressing reason to use a `UITextView`, such as there being other text being displayed, you could use a `UILabel` combined with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to get the effect you're looking for.

Otherwise, you could go with an actual `UIWebView` instead.

Comment: I am doing a lot of attributedString work in the UITextView, so I would prefer this over building an HTML string. Also, I need specific points of text to be selectable, not the entire text so UILabel is out too.

Comment: Yeah, but then there is no touch highlight.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `textview.delaysContentTouches = NO;` ? Maybe that could help.

Comment: I have - that was my first thought and is included in the code above. I know that UITextView inherits from UIScrollView, so I thought it was related to that somehow.

Comment: that was my first instinct as well. I'd then recommend you go ahead with working your way through `touchesBegan` & it's brothers and `attributesAtIndex` and check for the `NSLinkAttribute` if it exists.

Comment: How would you go about doing this? This sounds like re-implementing the link detection...

Comment: Also, where is the attributesAtIndex method?

Comment: Yes, it does seem so. The attributesAtIndex is available on the NSAttributedString of that UITextView. I can post some code later tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need editing, you can use this:

```
textView.isEditable = true
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool
{
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        return true
    }
```